# How can I optimize the code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have the follow lines of code:

```
 Protected Sub RepComisiones_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles RepComisiones.ItemDataBound
    Dim valoresRepeter As DataRowView


    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        valoresRepeter = e.Item.DataItem

        Select Case valoresRepeter("ECO").ToString
            Case "0"
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblEco"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select
        Select Case valoresRepeter("A").ToString
            Case 0
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblA"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select
        Select Case valoresRepeter("B1").ToString
            Case 0
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblB1"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select
        Select Case valoresRepeter("B2").ToString
            Case 0
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblB2"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select
        Select Case valoresRepeter("B3").ToString
            Case 0
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblB3"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select
        Select Case valoresRepeter("B3P").ToString
            Case 0
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblB3P"), Label).Text = ""
        End Select

    End If
End Sub
```

I want to reduce some lines, I try diferent ways but the result is not correct, any idea how can I optimize.

Thank you

Comment: That's really just a set of simple IF-THEN statements.  Case statements should never have just one choice, it's the wrong construct for that.

Comment: Please use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). Your first `Case "0"` is using a string as it should, but the following ones are using a number instead. Option Strict On would point that out to you.

Comment: Number of lines is not a good metric of efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and clean solution would be to put all keys ("ECO", "A", "B1") and their corresponding control names ("lblECO", "lblA", "lblB") in a dictionary and iterate through this for evaluating the individual conditions.

```
Private mappings As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
        {
            {"ECO", "lblEco"},
            {"A", "lblA"},
            {"B1", "lblB1"}
        }

Sub RepComisiones_ItemDataBound()

        For Each key As String In mappings.Keys
            If valoresRepeter(key).ToString Is "0" Then
                DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(mappings.Item(key)), Label).Text = ""
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```